# Tomcat 7 + Android: timeout on client side

Tags: timeout, tomcat7

I have a web service hosted in Tomcat using Jersey to provide the resources. The Android application establishes a secure connection to the Tomcat server, does some intensive processing, and calls a resource on the service.

The problem is that the client application throws an IO exception when reading from the stream.

I have the `readTimeout` set to 10 minutes on the client side. This should be enough since the processing on the client, between connection to server and resource request, takes around 2 minutes. Is there a setting I can enable on the Tomcat side to prevent the connection timeout? I believe Tomcat is the issue here.

Comment: I had similar problem and was related to the size of the data transmitted. readTimeOut parameters didn't work for me

Comment: @Emilio: thanks. The data transmitted is quite small. If I removed the intensive processing on the client side, which takes around 2 minutes, it works fine. That's why I'm assuming it's a timeout issue with the server.